# How to move the ArcGIS Pro camera?

Tags: arcgis-pro, animation, 3d-map

How do I move the ArcGIS Pro camera (in 3D)?
More importantly, how do I do it *programmatically*?

I'm trying to animate flying drone trajectories.

I have a Lon Lat Altitude (xyz) dataset (simple imported text file w/ 3 columns)  that I've been able to (somewhat) animate:

[trajectory.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q7MhjVh81a522EEc-J4xmdRmSbWXlCfq)

But the camera is stationary fixed above the feature.

I need a fly through w/ the camera position matching/paralleling (& moving with) the flight path/trajectory. I want the camera to be the drone.

I've been trying to find documentation/sample code but no luck.  Any suggestions would be helpful esp. where to find.

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.2.0

Comment: Have you tried using the Camera object of ArcPy?

Answer (score 2):

This blog post, with code demonstrates how to step through a featureclass of point locations, updating the camera with the ProSDK. You could probably modify the code to iterate through your list instead.

https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/3d-gis/animation-with-the-arcgis-pro-1-2-sdk-the-millennium-force-coaster-at-cedar-point/